# Problems with Python else statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I tried to input 1 in the object code but the  `else` statement always executes even though my if statement is equal to 1 and evaluates to true:

```
intro = input("Welcome to Gazebo  (Press Enter to continue)")
print ("Choose your menu  (Type the number for the corresponding option)")
print ("1 - Starters ")
print ("2 - Main Menu ")
print ("3 - Sweets ")
print ("4 - Cold drinks ")
print ("5 - Juices ")
print ("6 - Ice Creams ")
menu = input("e ")
if menu == 1 :
    print ("Choose your menu  (Type the number for the corresponding option)")
    print ("1 - Starters ")
    print ("2 - Main Menu ")
    print ("3 - Sweets ")
    print ("4 - Cold drinks ")
    print ("5 - Juices ")
    print ("6 - Ice Creams ")
    Str1 = input("Enter the corresponding number for the desired dish")
else :
    print ("Bye")
```

Answer (score 0):

The comparison in this line:

> ```
> if menu == 1 :
> ```

will always evaluate to `false` because you're not converting the input to a number before comparing, hence regardless of what you input the else statement will execute.

To fix this convert the input to a number using `int`, `float` but **not** `eval` (its usage is almost never required in daily-life usage, look up its dangers; provided this here only for information) and then comparisons should work as intended.